# How to extract data from list with RegExp OR in Python3?

Tags: python, regex, list

I have the following list

```
['Amount', 'amount', 'Line Total', 'lineTotal', 'AMOUNT DUE']
```

and I'm trying to extract 'Amount', 'amount', 'Line Total', 'lineTotal' but not 'AMOUNT DUE' field from that list.
Here is how I do that:

```
>>> lst = ['Amount', 'amount', 'Line Total', 'lineTotal', 'AMOUNT DUE']
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile("(line*|amount\b)", re.IGNORECASE)
```

I'm using regexp OR expression because in real use case I can have different values (e.g. in one of them can be only 'Amount' value and smth else, in the other one - 'Line Total' etc) and I want to extract exactly that one value depending on what I have.
So in example above I expect to get

```
['Amount', 'amount', 'Line Total', 'lineTotal']
```

But instead I'm getting

```
>>> list(filter(r.match, lst))
['Line Total', 'lineTotal']
```

Why is it happaning like so I how could I fix that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FMmfuF/1)):

```py
import re

lst = ["Amount", "amount", "Line Total", "lineTotal", "AMOUNT DUE"]
r = re.compile(r"(?=line|amount$).*", flags=re.IGNORECASE)

lst = list(filter(r.match, lst))
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
['Amount', 'amount', 'Line Total', 'lineTotal']
```